# Target item in python library

Tags: python, pi, psutil

I am trying to print just the **current temperature** only from the output using psutil on my raspberry pi with python.
Any help in altered inputs would be greatfully appreciated.

Input

```
Import psutil

print ((psutil.sensors_temperatures())
```

Output

```
{'cpu_thermal': [shwtemp(label='', current=36.998, high=None, critical=None)]}
```

I have tried several alteration to the input statement but not getting the output required

psutil.sensors_temperatures().current

psutil.sensors_temperatures().cpu_thermal.current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# get the temperature
cpu_temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()["cpu_thermal"][0]
print(cpu_temp.current)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You came from another programming language. Python is different:**

`psutil.sensors_temperatures()` Returns a dictionary, which is accessed with the syntax `dict["key"]`. Try this:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.sensors_temperatures()["cpu_thermal"].current)
```

For more on Python's dicts see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp